# I cannot compile when I use the flag -fast

Tags: compilation, icc

I am compiling using this command:

icc -O3 MD.c util.c control.c -o MD

and it works fine, but I want to use also the flag -fast

I compile like that:

icc -O3 -fast MD.c util.c control.c -o MD

and I receive the this message:

ld: cannot find -lm

ld: cannot find -lc

ld: cannot find -ldl

ld: cannot find -lc

Do I need to include any library?

P.S.:  I am using the compiler
intel-cc-17/17.0.2.174

Comment: It would help if you added a tag for the specific compiler you're using, and mentioned the version of that compiler in your post. There are many different compilers, and the sole tag *compilation* is pretty useless on its own.

Comment: `-Ofast` and `-fast` are both valid for ICC, but `-fast` apparently enables even more or better whole-program optimization.  With just `-Ofast`, https://godbolt.org/z/WhcOOq this program with a `noinline` function has a separate entry point for the inter-procedural constant-propagation version of it, but there's still a (broken?) entry point with the original symbol name.  With `-fast`, that other entry point goes away.  Maybe it also changes library search paths?  Try with `icc -v ...`

Comment: I tried as well like:  icc -v -O3 -fast .....  and I get more errors including the last ones.

Comment: the flag that cause compilation fail is this: -fp-model fast=1.  (which is included in the -fast falg). Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the why it doesn't compile.

The command is -Ofast. I used -Ofast and it works fine!

I usually find it in literature as -fast, that's why I used this command initially